# I/O scheduling on LVM on dm-crypt

Tags: linux, performance, lvm, io, device-mapper

I have the following setup:

- Stock Debian stable (Linux kernel 3.16.7) running on Dell PowerEdge R320
- Two SATA hard drives in RAID1 on a PERC H310 Mini controller, visible as `/dev/sda`
- dm-crypt target `dm-0` backed by `/dev/sda2`
- A single LVM volume group with a single aforementioned physical volume `dm-0`
- Multiple logical volumes `dm-1`, `dm-2` etc in the aforementioned volume group, formatted as `ext4`

What happens is when a single process starts bulk writing to a logical volume, all other processes get severely I/O starved - the system becomes very unresponsive (with delays of up to 30 seconds when I/O is involved).

I thought it's the I/O scheduler that's in charge of making sure that doesn't happen. I see that `sda` uses `cfq`:

```
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
noop deadline [cfq]
```

But every other device mapper target reports having no I/O scheduler:

```
# cat /sys/block/dm-0/queue/scheduler 
none
# cat /sys/block/dm-1/queue/scheduler 
none
# cat /sys/block/dm-2/queue/scheduler 
none
```

My question is, why is there no I/O scheduling for device mapper targets, can I enable it, or how can I otherwise make this system responsive under heavy I/O load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is perfectly normal that [DM devices does not have any I/O scheduler](https://blog.famzah.net/2010/01/25/why-sys-block-dm-0-queue-scheduler-exists-on-my-linux-system/), as (with specific exceptions)

About the low performance you recorded, consider that your H310 controller not only has no cache, but it *even disables the physical disk's DRAM cache*, meaning your system has no way to lower latency via caching.

Combining that with encryption, where read-modify-write is common behavior (due to unaligned write access to the encrypted container), results in exceptionally poor write I/O performance.

Comment: But the I/O performance is quite good, actually. Simple file copying happens at a sustained ~150MB/s, for example. The problem is that one process can totally hog the entire system, making every other process block for many seconds.

Comment: Because a file copy generally use large block size (>= 128KB). So, the single-threaded copy can proceed quite fast, but any other write activity can be stalled for (comparatively) long time. Anyway, consider that one process with heavy read/write activity can hog even a non-encrypted, cache-enabled machine. So much more for an encrypted, non-cached one.

Comment: I think you're right about H310, looks like a lot of people are having performance problems with it.